# QuickCheck for Collatz conjecture

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I need to Write a QuickCheck property to check the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) for a given number greater than 0.

My challenge is that my code for Collatz conjecture is recursive , so either I get to 1 as expected or loop for ever.

I'm not sure I know how to utilize QuickCheck  is this situation.

Any idea ?

Comment: The collatz conjecture is that all positive integers will eventually reach 1, so if your function goes into an actual loop (not just taking forever) without reaching 1, it’s almost certainly wrong. If your question is about finding out if it ever finishes, then you just stumbled upon the Halting problem and there’s no way out of that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: use the forAll combinator and a “Gen Int” generator. The function passed to forAll should implement the Collatz algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I read about  the forAll combinator  ? I searched  a round with no results.

Comment: @GilShafriri, [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=forAll&scope=set%3Astackage) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for an assignment to practice writing QuickCheck properties?

I suspect that the intention is that you write a test that succeeds if the Collatz recursion terminates with 1 (as it is conjectured to do for all positive integers) and loops forever otherwise.  In other words, you're not expected to detect that the recursion is looping forever (which you could only do by way of an approximation anyway, by giving up if it recursed for "too long").

So, if you have a recursive function `collatz :: Int -> Int` that returns `1` , then your QuickCheck property will ultimately boil down to `collatz n == 1`.  Depending on what you've learned about QuickCheck properties, you may just be expected to write:  `prop_collatz n = collatz n == 1` with an appropriate type signature.  Or, maybe you're supposed to use the `Property` type and `forAll`, and maybe you're supposed to use the `Positive` type to test only positive integers.  It's hard to know what your instructor is expecting.

I would suggest looking at some examples from class where you tested properties on positive or non-negative or otherwise constrained sets of integers and follow that example.